# Learning Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino

What is the best source to learn Cappuccino? I do "traditional" web development, but i'm very interested in this new framework. Please note that I have no knowledge of Objective-C.

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned above, the website is a good place, but there are also some other good resources:

- http://cappuccinocasts.com/ (screencasts)
- http://www.nice-panorama.com/Programmation/cappuccino/
- http://www.littletreesoftware.com/blog/
- http://theocacao.com/document.page/593

There are a few others too, and many of them are linked to from the site.

Comment: Certainly not much about Objective-J yet here on SO. Maybe it'll pick up when Atlas comes out. The webcasts are stunning. Is the language itself (Objective-J) changing much at this point? Or are you mainly addressing bugs and adding Cocoa-like functionality.

Comment: Thank you - helpful link. The documentation is still a bit sparse though. I was wondering whether there may a book coming out at some point. Maybe an O'Reilly book?

Comment: The language itself is pretty much stable and has been for a good year or so (aside possibly fixing bugs people may find).

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a real life cappuccino tutorial based on an actual customer project: http://www.springenwerk.com/2009/09/real-life-cappuccino-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: Do you still have the tutorial?

Comment: @user2924482 Yes, had to change the URL from `blog.` to `www.`. You might be better off reading a more up-to-date tutorial though. This one is 6 years old.

Comment: Cool it work. Do you know if cappuccino is compatible with Xcode 6 ?

Comment: @user2924482 I believe so.

Answer (score 3):

On the tutorials is says:

A great introduction to Objective-J. Familiarity with JavaScript is recommended, prior knowledge of Objective-C not required.

http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/

It seems the website is a good place to learn.  Interesting framework.

Answer (score 2):

You also have http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/

It is our new work-in-progress website. Not complete at all, it still has some very basic tutorials to help you starting coding with Cappuccino

Answer (score 1):

I recently took up learning cappuccino. I found the Cappuccino Casts and the tutorials on cappuccino.org, however, like you, I come from a web development background - not cocoa / desktop apps.

Following some online tutorials was good to a degree, but I felt I lacked fundamental knowledge about the Objective-C and Cocoa and Cappuccino is modelled so closely to it. I bough a copy of Aaron Hillegass' book called "Cocoa(R) Programming for Mac(R) OS X" here: [http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) which I felt really helped with my base understand of application development rather than traditional web development.

I would definitely recommend giving it a read, I worked my way through it in a few days and thought it gave enough knowledge to understand what all the Cappuccino stuf was about.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found that when I install Cappuccino from source, there is a fairly significant amount of code to learn from hidden away in `<install-dir>/Cappucino/Tests/Manual`

There is a wealth of code there that isn't advertised anywhere but is certainly good enough to learn from. Just drop the `Frameworks` next to the `index.html` file in each test folder and open up and learn!