# Resources for Learning Objective-J and Cappuccino?

Tags: cappuccino

I have noticed, for some odd reason there is absolutely no books out on the Cappuccino Web Framework, and Objective-J.

I would really like to learn these, but I cant find any resources other than the poorly set up (confluence-like) wiki/reference on the webpage.

Is there any other resources on Objective-J and Cappuccino? Preferably PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problems a while ago.

There is very few comprehensive tutorials on Cappuccino. Only some articles are available.
I would recommend to learn Cocoa first (especially AppKit and Foundations). Since Cappuccino is a port of Cocoa, you will find that your transition to Cappuccino and Objective-J would be smooth and easy.

Also some very good tutorials are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001517/learning-cappuccino?rq=1). Especially, I like this one:

http://www.nice-panorama.com/Programmation/cappuccino/